# Powershell rename file to directory with truncating name after a certain string

Tags: powershell, rename, truncate

I am trying to rename files in directories to the directory name but I need to truncate the name after a certain string in the directory name.

Example: Dir name "filename123_Release v.1"
I want the file in the directory to be called "filename123" (Leave the extension)

This is what I have to so far.  I need to truncate the names after "Release".  I don't want "Release" or anything after it in the file name.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\rename -Include *.mp4,*.mkv -Recurse   |Rename-Item -NewName  { $_.Directory.Name+$_.Extension}
```

Comment: Is `Release` always preceded by `_`?

Comment: No, it's random

Answer (score 1):

I got it working:

Get-ChildItem D:\rename -Include *.mp4,*.mkv -Recurse   |Rename-Item -NewName  { $*.Directory.Name.Substring(0,$*.Directory.Name.Indexof("Release"))+$_.Extension}

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

Essentially it splits the directory name into an array with [0] being the part before the word "Release". It's worth noting that based on your example you will be left with an underscore at the end of the file name which may not be the desired result.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Rename -Include *.mp4,*.mkv -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { ((($_.Directory.Name) -split 'Release')[0])+$_.Extension }
```